# Prove Arrow's Theorem is not true when there are two candidates

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to prove the Arrow's Theorem is not true when there are two candidates, however I'm having trouble trying to prove that there is no dictator. I have suggested that in a majority rules voting system, unanimity and IIA are satisfied but I have no idea how to prove that it isn't a dictatorship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictator has his way whenever he expresses strict preferences.

Suppose that in the majority rule, there is a dictator $d$ and suppose that $x\succ_d y$ for some choices $x$ and $y$. If everybody else has the reverse preference: $y\succ_i x$  for all $i\neq d$, what does the majority rule say about the social choice? Does $d$ get his way in this situation?

The majority rule is the correct candidate for your situation. It fails transitivity in general but when there are only 2 candidates, transitivity is vacuously satisfied

Comment: so you're saying that it doesn't matter what the dictator votes he is treated like a single person and majority will always rule?

Comment: I'm saying that if a dictator exists and he votes $x$ strictly over $y$, the social choice should choose $x$ over $y$. But this breaks down when the remaining voter(s) vote $y$ strictly over $x$: in this case, the majority rule will not rank $x$ strictly over $y$.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by the social choice should choose x over y?

Comment: The social choice (aka the social welfare function) is the mechanism that aggregates individuals' preferences.

Comment: gotcha, thanks a lot!